# what is the event for this product price print in home page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, home-page, product-prices

[image]

when i open that *Lenovo storage 1.2 T*

**product**

[image]

> I customized the product price by this event
>
> 1)catalog_product_get_final_price
>
> 2)catalog_product_collection_load_after
>
> 3)checkout_cart_product_add_after

but home page products showing the wrong
price

**how I can fix with my customized event product price for those blocks??**

my Magento ver 2.2.6

Comment: How you are displaying product collection to the home page?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using widgets for displaying product on the home page.
Then you can create a custom phtml file and update the price based on your requirements.